# How to Implement DialogBox and onLongClick at the same time on the button?

Tags: android, button, android-dialog, onlongclicklistener

I am working `onLongClickListner` and `DialogBox` I wanted to add `button`, when i click on it open a `dialogBox` (It first ask do you want to select the button) after click on the DialogButton `True` it comes back to selected `button` then it hold `button` for a while to check the answer and If the answer is correct then it show Message "Answer is true" and wrong it show Message"Answer is False".

**Here Is my code :-**

```
public class QuestionActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
private Question currentQ;
private GamePlay currentGame;




@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.question);
    processSession();

}
private void processSession(){
            /**
     * Configure current game and get question
     */
    currentGame = ((CYKApplication)getApplication()).getCurrentGame();
    currentQ = currentGame.getNextQuestion();
    Button nextBtn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
    nextBtn1.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button nextBtn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
    nextBtn2.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button nextBtn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
    nextBtn3.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button nextBtn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer4);
    nextBtn4.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button nextBtn5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer5);
    nextBtn5.setOnClickListener(this);
    /**
     * Update the question and answer options..
     */
    setQuestions();

}


/**
 * Method to set the text for the question and answers from the current games
 * current question
 */
private void setQuestions() {
    //set the question text from current question
    String question = Utility.capitalise(currentQ.getQuestion());
    TextView qText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
    qText.setText(question);

    //set the available options
    List<String> answers = currentQ.getQuestionOptions();
    TextView option1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
    option1.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(0)));

    TextView option2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
    option2.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(1)));

    TextView option3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
    option3.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(2)));

    TextView option4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer4);
    option4.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(3)));


    int score = currentGame.getScore();
    String scr = String.valueOf(score);
    TextView score1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
    score1.setText(scr);
  try{ 
     new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            TextView timers = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timers);
            timers.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        public void onFinish() { 
            currentGame.decrementScore();
            processSession();
               }
     }.start();
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
      throw new RuntimeException(ex);
  }
    }


@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    //Log.d("Questions", "Moving to next question");
    if(arg0.getId()==R.id.answer5)
    {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage("Are you sure?").setCancelable(true).setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
            finish();
             }
         }).setNegativeButton("No", null).show();

            }

    else
    {

        if(!checkAnswer(arg0)) return;  

    /**
     * check if end of game
     */
    if (currentGame.isGameOver()){
        //Log.d("Questions", "End of game! lets add up the scores..");
        //Log.d("Questions", "Questions Correct: " + currentGame.getRight());
        //Log.d("Questions", "Questions Wrong: " + currentGame.getWrong());
        Intent i = new Intent(this, EndgameActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
    else{
        Intent i = new Intent(this, QuestionActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
      }
    }
  }



@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    switch (keyCode)
    {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK :
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}


/**
 * Check if a checkbox has been selected, and if it
 * has then check if its correct and update gamescore
 */
private boolean checkAnswer(View view) {

    Button b=(Button) view;
    String answer = b.getText().toString();

    b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ans);
         // disable the button for further clicks.
         b.setEnabled(false);
        //Log.d("Questions", "Valid Checkbox selection made - check if correct");
        if (currentQ.getAnswer().equalsIgnoreCase(answer))
        {
            b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ansgreen);
            //Log.d("Questions", "Correct Answer!");
            currentGame.incrementScore();
        }
        else{
            b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ansred);
            //Log.d("Questions", "Incorrect Answer!");
            currentGame.decrementScore();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Any answer is appreciable.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show answer with longClick on button you should attach onLongClickListener to this button.

1. Implement onLongClickListener to your class
2. In overrided method "onLongClick" write code that describes what answer you want to show.

Comment: Welcome for reply!!i wanted to add Dailog First onclick button after that i wanted to hold my button to check for a while.If my answer is correct then it shows the message your answer is correct or not.