# How to disable other buttons till the first button is selected with delay in android?

Tags: android, button

I have got four buttons when I click my first Answer button with some delay but during delay when I click other buttons they all are selected. so need to disable other buttons until my first answer button is clicked and when the user returns back all the buttons need to be enabled. How can i solve this problem? Please help!!

**Here is my Code:-**

```
public class QuestionActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    private Question currentQ;
    private GamePlay currentGame;
    private CountDownTimer counterTimer;

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.question);
                processScreen();
         }
                /**
         * Configure current game and get question
         */
         private void processScreen()
         {
        currentGame = ((CYKApplication)getApplication()).getCurrentGame();
        currentQ = currentGame.getNextQuestion();
        Button nextBtn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
        nextBtn1.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button nextBtn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
        nextBtn2.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button nextBtn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
        nextBtn3.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button nextBtn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer4);
        nextBtn4.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button nextBtn5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer5);
        nextBtn5.setOnClickListener(this);
        /**
         * Update the question and answer options..
         */
        setQuestions();

    }


    /**
     * Method to set the text for the question and answers from the current games
     * current question
     */
    private void setQuestions() {
        //set the question text from current question
        String question = Utility.capitalise(currentQ.getQuestion());
        TextView qText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
        qText.setText(question);

        //set the available options
        List<String> answers = currentQ.getQuestionOptions();
        TextView option1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
        option1.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(0)));

        TextView option2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
        option2.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(1)));

        TextView option3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
        option3.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(2)));

        TextView option4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer4);
        option4.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(3)));

        int score = currentGame.getScore();
        String scr = String.valueOf(score);
        TextView score1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
        score1.setText(scr);

        counterTimer=new CountDownTimer(15000, 1000) {
            public void onFinish() {                
                if(currentGame.getRound()==20)
                System.exit(0);
                Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Time's up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                currentGame.decrementScore();
                final Handler handle = new Handler();
                Runnable delay = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        processScreen();
                    }
                };
                handle.postDelayed(delay,3000);
                 }

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                TextView time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timers);
                time.setText( ""+millisUntilFinished/1000);
                                }
        };
        counterTimer.start();
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        //Log.d("Questions", "Moving to next question");
        if(arg0.getId()==R.id.answer5)
        {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setMessage("Are you sure?")
        .setCancelable(true)
        .setPositiveButton("Yes",
         new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
         int id) {
                finish();
                 }
             }).setNegativeButton("No", null).show();

                }

        else
        {

            if(!checkAnswer(arg0)) return;  

        /**
         * check if end of game
         */
        if (currentGame.isGameOver()){
            //Log.d("Questions", "End of game! lets add up the scores..");
            //Log.d("Questions", "Questions Correct: " + currentGame.getRight());
            //Log.d("Questions", "Questions Wrong: " + currentGame.getWrong());
            final Handler handle = new Handler();
            Runnable delay = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    startActivity(new Intent(QuestionActivity.this, EndgameActivity.class));
                    finish();
                }
            };
            handle.postDelayed(delay,2000);

        }
            else
            {
                final Handler handle = new Handler();
                Runnable delay = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                   startActivity(new Intent(QuestionActivity.this, QuestionActivity.class));
                   finish();
                    }
                };
                handle.postDelayed(delay,2000);
                      }
                  }
              }



    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        switch (keyCode)
        {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK :
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


    /**
     * Check if a checkbox has been selected, and if it
     * has then check if its correct and update gamescore
     */
    private boolean checkAnswer(View v) {
        final Button b = (Button) v;
        String answer = b.getText().toString();
         counterTimer.cancel();
         b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ans);
         b.setEnabled(false);
        //Log.d("Questions", "Valid Checkbox selection made - check if correct");
            if (currentQ.getAnswer().equalsIgnoreCase(answer))
                {
                b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ansgreen);
                //Log.d("Questions", "Correct Answer!");
                Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Correct Answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                currentGame.incrementScore();
                }

            else{
                b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ansred);
                //Log.d("Questions", "Incorrect Answer!");
                Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Incorrect Answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                currentGame.decrementScore1();
                            }
            return true;
        }

}
```

Comment: use a radiobutton's with radio group you can check only 1 at a time.

Comment: @Raghunandan i already used buttons so can any group for buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move buttons declaration from `onCreate` to Activity members

```
private Button nextBtn1;
private Button nextBtn2;
private Button nextBtn3;
private Button nextBtn4;
private Button nextBtn5;
```

Put the code in the beggining of `onClick` method

```
nextBtn1.setEnabled(false);
nextBtn2.setEnabled(false);
nextBtn3.setEnabled(false);
nextBtn4.setEnabled(false);
nextBtn5.setEnabled(false);
arg0.setEnabled(true);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @ChandanKumar the code enables only the clicked view(which is `arg0` actually) and all the rest are marked as `disabled`

Comment: ok..Great for reply and answer.If i have further problem i will ask from you.stay in touch.

Comment: can u help me on dialog open  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007017/how-to-implement-dialogbox-and-onlongclick-at-the-same-time-on-the-button)

Answer (score 0):

```
Disable all other buttons other than button1 initially with button.setEnabled(false).

Eg: button2.setEnabled(false);
    button3.setEnabled(false);
    button.setEnabled(false);

Then in the onClick() method of first button enable all the buttons which u disabled at the first usingg button.setEnabled(true);

button1.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener(){

public void onClick()
{
 button2.setEnabled(true);
    button3.setEnabled(true);
    button.setEnabled(true);
}
};
```